# Ghostscript - pread - einval (invalid argument) issue

Tags: linux, ghostscript

We are using Ghostscript to extract the first page from PDFs and sometimes the gs process is stuck with the error message `pread(4, 0x21c56910, 32768, 18446744073709518848) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

I searched around, but just found a reference to some android related issues with filesystem. But we are using a RHEL 6 machine to do this, so the cause in android filesystem may not be relevant to our problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's clearly a file system error. Its not, however, a Ghostscript error. By which I mean that Ghostscript won't, as far as I can tell, throw an error with that text.

If pread fails Ghostscript should give you an error, but I think it will most likely be a PostScript ioerror.

The invalid argument is, presumably, the enormous third argument. That looks like its trying to read form a file offset some 18 exabytes into the file, which looks pretty unlikely to me.

I would expect this to be reproducible. Your best bet is to find a file which exhibits this behaviour and check that you can reproduce the problem. If you can't then its likely memory corruption, and so will be well-nigh impossible to reproduce or fix.

In either case I would suggest checking the current version of Ghostscript if that isn't what you are already using. It is possible that the code is not properly checking a return value and is trying to read bytes and continuously failing or something.

If it continues to exhibit this problem then you should open a bug report at https://bugs.ghostscript.com. You will need to attach an example file, and a command line which reproduces the problem.

Comment: It's not a big PDF, but has a huge resolution - 14400*14400.

Comment: PDF files don't have a resolution, perhaps you mean a huge media size ? If you can share the PDF file I can look at it, but its not really possible to say much more than that. Its also possible that the PDF file is simply broken.

Comment: I meant, the PDF is converted from a ppt, I verified the resolution by zooming it to 6400% and it was crystal clear. Sorry, I can't share the file, but I can try to create a similar file and see if that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Seriously, PDF files don't have a resolution. If the file consists solely of an image, then that image can have a resolution, but PDF files only have a media size. Zooming in on a PDF fiel which consists of vector information on the other hand, is 'crystal clear' no matter what resolution (ie zoom factor) you render it at, because the vectors are rendered to the bitmap at the current resolution.